# Linked List Different Output On Slight Change

Tags: java, object, linked-list

Here is code:

```
public void insertAtindex(int index,int data)
{
    Node node=new Node();
    node.data=data;
    Node n;
    n=head;
    for(int i=0;i<index-1;i++)
    {
        n=n.refrence;


    }
    Node temp=n;

    n.refrence=node;
      node.refrence=temp;
}
```

This is my input data:

[image]

This giving response is continuous Loop. I have attached the output:

[image]

But if I

```
public void insertAtindex(int index,int data)
{
    Node node=new Node();
    node.data=data;
    Node n;
    n=head;
    for(int i=0;i<index-1;i++)
    {
        n=n.refrence;
    }
    Node temp=n.refrence;

    n.refrence=node;
      node.refrence=temp;
}
```

Output:

[image]

This works. What's the problem?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

Of course the two snippets produce different output.

In the first snippet, you insert `node` before `n`, and you make `n.reference` refer to `node`, creating a circular list of two nodes.

Suppose that prior to the declaration of `temp`, `n` references node X and `n.reference` references node Y. `node` is referencing node NEW.

Let's illustrate the assignments you perform:

```
 X    ->    Y
 ^
 |
 n==temp

 X    ->   NEW
 ^          ^
 |          |
 n==temp   node

 X     -> NEW -> X
 ^         ^
 |         |
 n==temp  node
```

Hence `node.reference.reference == node`. You have a cycle.

In the second snippet, you insert `node` between `n` and the `Node` following it. That's probably the correct implementation.

Let's illustrate again the assignments you perform:

```
 X   ->   Y
 ^        ^
 |        |
 n       temp

 X -> NEW    Y
 ^     ^     ^
 |     |     |
 n    node  temp

 X -> NEW  -> Y
 ^     ^      ^
 |     |      |
 n    node   temp
```

You inserted the NEW node between nodes X and Y.